# jquery/javascript - howto compare arrays, retrieve array(s) with highest number of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm sitting over the following array-problem:

- I have four arrays 1,2,3,4
- each can contain any number of elements
- I'm looking for the array(s) with the highest number of elements (and its 2nd to last element)

I'm using this:

```
var arr = [],
$panels = $(':jqmData(hash="history")'),
$panels.each(function(index) {
     //data("stack") contains the array
     arr.push($(this).data("stack"));
     });
arr.sort(function(a,b){return b.length - a.length});
console.log( arr[0] );
```

So if the arrays look like this:
`[a,b,c] [d,e] [f,g,h,i] [k,l]`  console says `[ [f,g,h,i] ]`

OK, but if two arrays have the same highest length, like so:
`[a,b,c,d] [d,e] [f,g,h,i] [k,l]`  I don't get `[ [a,b,c,d] [f,g,h,i] ]`

because `arr[0]` will only return the first array again.

I'm clueless...

Is there a way to give me the array or arrays with the highest number of elements and their 2nd-to-last respective element?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add a simple loop which iterates over the arrays and collects every array which has the same length as the first one. As your result is already sorted, you don't even have to iterate over all of them.

Comment: so a loop looking for arr[0].length?

Comment: That's what I mean. The first array is already the longest one. *Edit:* yes, something like `var result = [], mlength = arr[0].length; for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) { if(arr[i].length < mlength) break; result.push(arr[i]); }`. That said, there might be still other, better, ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var longest = [];
var longestLen = 0;
$('div:jqmData(hash="history")').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data("stack");
    if(data.length > longestLen){
        longest = [data];
        longestLen = data.length;
    }
    else if(data.length == longestLen) longest.push(data)
})
```

### What happens?

1. `var data = ...` The array is retrieved.
2. `if(data.length > longestLen)` - Comparing the length of the current array to the known longest length.
   If the new array has a greater size, replace `longest` by a new array consisting of element `data`.
   Update `longestLen` to the length of the current longest array.
3. `else if(data.length == longestLen) longest.push(data)` - If the current array has the same length as the longest array, push the current array in the existing array `longest`.

Comment: I think I like this. Trying (and trying to understand...)

Comment: @frequent Updated answer with explanation and a small fix.

Comment: @frequent `.pop` removes and returns the **last** element from an array. If you want to get a copy of the **2nd-to-last** element, use `data = data.splice(1)`.

Comment: Thanks. I was cutting off the last element and then grab the "new" last element. Using you way now though.

Comment: @frequent Hang on, are you looking for the "element before the last element" + "last element"? In that case, use `element.splice(-2)` (get the last two elements from an array).

Answer (score 1):

You can map the arrays to their length, and only return the elements with the highest amount of elements (which is the amount of the first element in the sorted array):

```
[[1, 2], [7], [3, 4], [], [5]] // the array

.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
    // sort by highest to lowest amount of elements
})

.filter(function(value, index, array) {
    return value.length === array[0].length;
    // filter by highest length (length of first element)
});

// [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: hm. also trying this. Thanks so far

Comment: @frequent: It was a little excessive. Tried to make it more readable.

Comment: I also got this to work, but I'm liking the above better. Still, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayFunc(arr) {
    var c = [[]];
    $.each(arr, function(key, value) { 
        if(c[0].length == value.length) {
            c.push([value]);
        }
        else {
            if(c[0].length <= value.length) {
                c = [];
                c.push(value);
            }
        }
    });
    return c;
}

var a = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3],[0,1]];
var b = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3],[0,1],[0,1,3,4]];

console.log('result var a');
console.dir(arrayFunc(a));

console.log('result var b');
console.dir(arrayFunc(b));
```